# How to use {id} from path with Messanger input on Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have something like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM/Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "put_cancel": {
 *             "method": "PUT",
 *             "path": "/task/{id}/cancel",
 *             "messenger": "input",
 *             "input": CancelTaskCommand::class,
 *             "output": false
 *         },
 *     }
 * )
 */
class Foo {}
```

CancelFooCommand.php

```php
final class CancelFooCommand
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ApiProperty(
     *     identifier=true,
     * )
     */
    public string $id = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ApiProperty(
     *     attributes={
     *         "openapi_context"={
     *           "type": "string"
     *         }
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public string $note = '';
}
```

So I have to enter the id twice, in payload and in path. Is it possible to skip adding `id` to payload and get it from path?